# How to get Path to a copied file in the application directory

Tags: c#, resources

I have some files I added to the resources of my application.
These files have the "Copy to Output Directory" property set to "Copy always", so the files will appear in the *applicationDirectiry/Resources* directory.

What I want is access to those files. Of course I could use the following code:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory 
 + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
 + "Resources\ResourceFileName.xslt";
```

The problem here is, that if I want to rename a file or the *\Resources* directory, I would have to modify all strings.

EDIT: For example I have a *MasterData.xslt* file in my resources. After the build it will placed in the _ApplicationFolder\Resources_ directory. The path to that file is *ApplicationFolder\Resources\MasterData.xslt*. In my code I can access the content of that file by using

```
Resources.MasterData
```

Is there a way to get the file path (*ApplicationFolder\Resources\MasterData.xslt*) instead of its content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Resources is a sub-directory below your application's runtime directory, you can do this:

```
string fileName = 
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location +    
    Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + 
    "Resources" + 
    Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
    "ResourceFileName.xslt";
```

Note also I used Path.DirectorySeparatorChar twice instead of the "\".

Answer (score 2):

When you place the files there during a Build, the location should be considered a 'magical' constant.

Just use a `const string resFolder = "Resources";` somewhere so that you have a Single Point of Definition.

OT: And use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to construct file-paths:

```
 string myPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, 
        resFolder, "ResourceFileName.xslt");
```

Comment: Not answerable from the question. It drops from the sky as a constant.